# Do I need to purchase IOS development ID for testing on IOS real devices via protractor for webapp on safari?

Tags: typescript, protractor, appium

I am trying to test my webapp on IPad mini 4 on safari via protractor & appium. But getting error on launching the safari app. I am able to launch the iOS simulators that is available on Xcode but when running on real device I got error with the same config file. Do I need to purchase apple developer licence to test on real device on safari browser?

Here is my config file:

```
capabilities: { 
        automationName: 'XCUITest',
        browserName: 'safari',
        bundleid:'com.apple.mobilesafari',
        //appium-version: '1.13.0',
        platformName: 'iOS',
        platformVersion: '12.2',
        deviceName:'tarun iPad',
        noreset:true,
        udid: "auto",
        //xcodeOrgId: "<Team ID>",
      //xcodeSigningId: ''

    },
```

System and software versions using:

```
mac OS mojave: 10.14.3 (18D109)
Xcode: Version 10.2.1 (10E1001)
node: 11.2.0
npm: 6 .4.1
appium 1.13.0
```

Getting this below error on running on real device:

```
info XCUITest xcodebuild exited with code '65'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purchasing a developer account is not mandatory as long as you're not intending to publish anything to the [AppStore](https://www.apple.com/ios/app-store/)

1. Create a free Apple ID at https://appleid.apple.com/account
2. Add the newly created AppleID to XCode
3. Create iOS development certificate
4. Now follow steps from the [Appium XCUITest Driver Real Device Setup](http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/ios-xcuitest-real-devices/)

References:

- [How to Create a Free iOS Development Provisioning Profile](https://livecode.com/how-to-create-a-free-ios-development-provisioning-profile/)
- [Configuring Appium Environment for iOS Real Device](https://medium.com/@marjorieivy/configuring-appium-environment-for-ios-real-device-310c7bc863e4)
- [When Appium for iOS is not getting it done, enter Appium Studio](https://experitest.com/appium/when-appium-for-ios-is-not-getting-it-done-enter-appium-studio/)